# Directory Listing program in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm writing a directory listing program in C. This is what I have so far. However when I type in mydir in command prompt. It doesn't print out anything. And the program doesn't crash. Can someone help me point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA found; // Search buffer
    HANDLE hFind; // Search handle
    BOOL fullpath = FALSE; // Full Path requested
    char path[MAX_PATH] = ""; // Specified path
    char pattern[MAX_PATH]; // Search pattern
    char orgpath[MAX_PATH];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) { // Extract parameters from commandline
        if (_stricmp(argv[i], "/?") == 0)
            printf("[Usage] mydir [/L] <subdirectory path>\n");
        else
            if (_stricmp(argv[i], "/L") == 0) fullpath = TRUE;
            else strcpy_s(path, MAX_PATH, argv[i]); // Save path specification
    }
    // Check to see if user-specified path exists
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, orgpath);
    if ((strcmp(path, "") != 0) && !SetCurrentDirectory(path)) {
        printf("[Usage] Invalid <subdirectory path> specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Obtain Full Path if requested
    if (fullpath) GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
    SetCurrentDirectory(orgpath); // Restore original path
    // Add \ to end of path, if necessary *********************
    if (strcmp(path, "") != 0 && // path specified
        path[strlen(path) - 1] != ':' && // Not just drive letter
        path[strlen(path) - 1] != '\\') // Doesn't end in \     
    {
            strcat_s(path, MAX_PATH, "\\"); // Add \ at end
    }

    strcpy_s(pattern, MAX_PATH, path);
    strcat_s(pattern, MAX_PATH, "*.*"); // Search for all files
    hFind = FindFirstFile(pattern, &found);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { // Found a first file
        do {
            if ((strcmp(found.cFileName, ".") != 0) &&
                (strcmp(found.cFileName, "..") != 0)) {
                printf("%s%s\n", path, found.cFileName);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &found));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Suggest that you add some printfs down at the bottom where you finally get around to calling `FindFirstFile`. I'm guessing that `FindFirstFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, because one of these is always `true`. `strcmp()` returns 0 in case both strings are equal. By ensuring both calls return a value other than 0, you ensure that you don't have `.` nor `..`.

Comment: @Mario Aha !! i somehow missed the `!= 0` part. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. I was using unicode character set in my project and passing ascii string. I changed the property to Multi-Byte character set and it work now.